# How to bind dictionary object in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, gridview

I am facing problem while binding a dictionary object in gridview.

```
        Dictionary<string, int[]> final_list = (Dictionary<string, int[]>)Session["InstrumentBatch"];
        //The data gets populated in the final_list

        List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>> kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>>();
        kvp.AddRange(final_list);
        //Adding it to a list because Dictionary is not bind able in gridview.

    gvData.DataSource = kvp;
    gvData.DataBind();
```

What should i write in my .aspx page to populate data in my gridview. Anytype of help is welcomed. Feel free to ask any question

I want to show The headers as **InstrumentType** (Dictionary-Key) and the **NEW, LN, PR, ANY** (Dictionary Values).

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends a lot on what you want to show on the page. Generally KeyValuePair exposes two properties, Key and Value (who could have guessed!), so you can use these in the grid view. Say in BoundField:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Key" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Value" />
```

However in your case this won't necessarily work as you would expect, because your value is an array. For that you can use some kind of a template:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# String.Join(",", ((int[])Eval("Value"))) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Separating out values of the array per columns is also possible with TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value 0">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ((int[])Eval("Value"))[0] %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value 1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ((int[])Eval("Value"))[1] %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
```

Comment: i want to have 4 columns for my dictionary value..as the array will be having 4 values...is it possible that way @Andrei

Comment: @Arka, very possible. Inside `<%# %>` it is just the C# code, so such things are not a problem at all

Comment: Thanks Buddy...You saved my day @Andrei

Answer (score 1):

It is Possible.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Dictionary Key" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Dictionary Value" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

First add the values.

```
 Dictionary<string, int[]> final_list = (Dictionary<string, int[]>)
 final_list.add(key,value);
 final_list.add(key, value);
```

then bind it,

```
 gridview.DataSource=final_list;
 gridView.DataBind();
```